# Need proper pace training for a 1.5 mile run on a treadmill

Tags: running, training, treadmill

What is the proper pace training for a 1.5 mile run on a treadmill? When I was training for the PAT for Correction Officer in the past, I remember there being a time/speed increase at small intervals. I would like to ultimately run it in 11-12 mins. Please note, that my beginning point will be from the standpoint of not running on a treadmill at all. I'm also looking for a weekly/monthly schedule to improve this distance.

Comment: I'd start with any of the Couch 2 5k programs, and then the Macmillan running site listed in an answer below is also an excellent resource.

Answer (score 2):

I use [this site](http://www.mcmillanrunning.com/) to work out what pace I need to be running at to hit target times. You put in your current time for a certain distance, the target time you want to do for that distance then it tell you how fast you need to be running for specific distances to hit that target time. It also tells you what pace you should be running each type of run. Easy/tempo/speed work/long run etc.

For a short distance like 1.5 miles, I would recommend some short, sharp intervals (say, 5 or 6 reps of 0.25k hard, 0.25k/0.5k recovery) then some longer slow runs, say 3 to 5 miles. As the weeks progress then increase the speed and/or quantity of interval reps. On a treadmill you have the advantage of being able to pace and time your training very accurately. I wouldn't neglect the roads though. I find treadmill running very boring so if I were you I'd do my longer runs on the road. Each to their own though. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The 1.5 mile run is also used in the U.S. Navy PT testing. Any time lower than 13:30 is passing, so I think 11 - 12 minutes isn't a bad target (assuming the qualifying is comparable).

You can use this to [calculate a good average treadmill pace](https://excelkits.com/treadmill-pace-calculator?distance=1.5&time=00%3A12%3A00&unit=Miles&incline=0.01#primary) for 12 minutes which is 8 min/mile which is a speed setting of 7.5.

Ideally you're able to hit 11:00, which would be a pace of 7:20 using the speed setting 8.2 to give you some breathing room in your examination.